# Data on causatives in Russian and Turkish needed!

Tags: syntax, turkish, russian, passive, causative

I'm working on a comparative syntactic project on the notion 'causative', either morphologically marked or non-marked. References like Haspelmath (1987) provide some (brief) data on the notion of causative/anticausative in a crosslinguistic manner, still I need more references on causatives in Turkish and Russian to explore this notion in different syntactic environements and see how it interact with the passive.

I would be grateful if you could refer me to somere references on causatives (& passives) in Russian or Turkish.

Thank you.

Comment: You could just ask Haspelmath directly, he is fairly accessible.  I assume you know that Russian causative is not morphological anyway.

Comment: Thank you Adam. I thought there might be some linguists who work on Russian & Turkish morphology to provide some references. No, I'm not aware that Russian causative is not morphological..I'll take your advice and contact Haspelmath.